# "Active Directory Users and Computers" MMC snap-in for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

Is there an equivalent tool available for use in Windows 7?  I just need to browse the membership of some small Active Directory groups that are deep within a huge hierarchy, so I can eventually write code to work with those groups.  The Windows Server 2003 version of the installer works, but the resulting MMC snap in just won't start up.

EDIT:
I'd like to preemptively strike against more requests to close the question.  This is a tool that I assume many programmers use to assist in programming-related tasks such as testing code that modifies Active Directory content.  There are tons of other questions about developer tools here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 for preemptive strike

Comment: Chris, it's sad, these days that preemptive strike would have just provoked closes! There is an ever-increasing mindset amongst the site's moderators and top users to be overly strict - and it is severly decreasing the site's usefulness. If it continues it won't be 2019 before the site declines to a point where competitors take over, which will be really sad, because it's a great concept.

Comment: Preempted or not, this question violates the current posting guidelines, and should be closed, if nothing else then to dissuade users from posting many many more questions about any tool, book, or sitcom which may be somehow interesting for programmers.

Comment: Software tools that may be pertinent to the execution of an IT administrator's​ (or programmer's) specifically programming or IT admin related tasks are, in terms of relevance, apparently in the same category as “interesting sitcoms” for the Stack Overflow admins.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

For Windows Vista and Windows 7 you need to get the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) - the Active Directory Users & Computers Snap-In is included in that pack. Download link: [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en).

Comment: Yeah, this worked nicely.  Thanks!  I wasn't aware of this toolset.  It took a while both because I was too impatient to properly uninstall the 2003 stuff, and then I was reluctant to reboot my machine when the installer wanted me to.

Comment: Excellent answer! That was what I was looking for. I did not have to reboot when installing it.

Comment: See also comment below from Craig Hyatt ("Turn Windows features on or off" to activate "AD DS and AD LDS Tools"). To connect to a domain with a non-domain PC I've used `runas /netonly /user:<DOMAIN>\<USER> mmc`, added the Snap-In "Active Directory Users and Computers", and used "Connect to domain..." feature.

Answer (score 48):

Per Noalt's answer is correct.  However, if you want the snap-in mentioned in the title (Users and Computers), you'll also have to run these commands at a command-line afterwards, as an Administrator:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS-SnapIns
```

Note - I had to run these in order for AD Users and Computers to show up, as they were disabled on my computer after the install.  This might not be the case for all users.

Comment: according to the documentation on the RSAT download page you can also do this via the Programs and Features control panel applet

Comment: Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Remote Server Administration Tools -> AD DS and AD LDS Tools:

Comment: @CraigHyatt - this did the trick for me on Server 2008. I am adding this as answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

I'm not allowed to use `Turn Windows features on or off`, but running all of these commands in an elevated command prompt (Run as Administrator) finally got `Active Directory Users and Computers` to show up under `Administrative Tools` on the start menu:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS-SnapIns
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS-AdministrativeCenter
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS-NIS
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-LDS
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell
```

I had downloaded and installed the RSAT ([Windows 7 Link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7887), [Windows Vista Link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21090)) before running these commands.

It's quite likely that this is more than you features than you actually need, but at least it's not too few.

Answer (score 10):

RE: enabling features via the command line


Alternatively, you can enable whichever features you're interested in via the Programs and Features control panel

From the download page Per Noalt provided:

> Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Programs.
>
> 1. In the Programs and Features area, click Turn Windows features on
>      or off.
> 2. If you are prompted by User Account Control to enable the Windows
>      Features dialog box to open, click Continue.
> 3. In the Windows Features dialog box, expand Remote Server
>      Administration Tools.
> 4. Select the remote management tools that you want to install.

Answer (score 9):

As @CraigHyatt mentioned in one of the comments:

"Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Remote Server Administration Tools -> AD DS and AD LDS Tools"

This worked like a charm in Windows Server 2008. A reboot was necessary, but the `Active Directory Users and Computers` snap in was available after that.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question is old, but it is first in google searches

For the windows 8.1, the tools can be downloaded here
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2693643

For the windows 10, the tools can be downloaded here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

EDIT: After installing the Windows 10 2015 "Fall Update", I had to reinstall the remote server administration tools.

Answer (score 2):

The commands from WEFX worked for me after I enabled the parent features  RemoteServerAdministrationTools, RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles, and RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD

Comment: This is the same issue I got. Installed RSAT tools (Per Noalt), then still couldn't see Active Directory Users and Computers (in Start menu or as an MMC add-in) until I enabled all the parent features and snapins using the information both Karen and WEFX mention. After which, I can see it in both MMC and in my start menu.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys it exist a much more sexy tool for a developper to have a look into a Directory, whatever the Directory is (Active-Directory, OpenLDAP, eDirectory ...) its name is [Apache Directory studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), it works in the same way on the top of java in Windows or in Linux. It's a kind of universal LDP.EXE for those who know this tool on Windows Servers. It allows to create LDIF files and also to browse the SCHEMA.

Answer (score 2):

As "me1" has mentioned you can do this assuming that your version of Windows 7 is either Professional or Ultimate, the PC is on the domain and you have preinstall the Remote Server Administration Tools (Windows6.1-KB958830-x64-RefreshPkg.msu or newer) then you'll be able to do the following:

Step 1. Select "Start", select "Control Panel", select "Programs" and click on "Turn Windows features on or off".

Step 2. Check the following 5 features:

"remote server administration tools>feature administration tools>group policy management tools"

"remote server administration tools>feature administration tools>smtp server tools"

"remote server administration tools>role administration tools>ad ds and ad lds tools>active directory module for windows powershell"

"remote server administration tools>role administration tools>ad ds and ad lds tools>ad ds tools>active directory administrative center"

"remote server administration tools>role administration tools>ad ds and ad lds tools>ad ds tools>ad ds snap-ins and command-line tools"

Step 3. Click "OK".

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the features in **Add/Remove Programs** section of your **Control Panel**. Select "Turn Windows features on or off"

Answer (score 0):

There are new instructions as of the Windows 10 October 2018 update:

> Just go to "Manage optional features" in Settings and click "Add a feature" to see the list of available RSAT tools. Select and install the specific RSAT tools you need. To see installation progress, click the Back button to view status on the "Manage optional features" page.

Source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520